# Setting the edit position on the Datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I recently wanted to make sure that a specific cell is ready to be edited. 
So I try to use editedItemPosition property on the datagrid, but cell is not editing.

For information, my datagrid use itemrenderer and editorrenderer and datagrid editable property is true.

```
   private function setSelectedItem():void
{
    var gData:Object = dgSuiviClini.dataProvider;
    var todayDate:String= new DateUtility().DateAsToString(new Date());

    for(var i:Number=0; i < gData.length; i++)
    {
        var thisObj:Object = gData.getItemAt(i);
        if(thisObj.grDateDeb == todayDate)
        {
            dgSuiviClini.selectedIndex = i;
            //sometimes scrollToIndex doesnt work if validateNow() not done
            dgSuiviClini.validateNow();
                //dgSuiviClini.scrollToIndex(i);
        }
        else{
            dgSuiviClini.validateNow();
                // dgSuiviClini.scrollToIndex(gData.length);


        }
    }
    dgSuiviClini.validateNow();
    dgSuiviClini.editedItemPosition = { rowIndex: gData.length-1, columnIndex: 3 };


}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Now, it works with this code

```
    private function setSelectedItem():void
{
    var gData:Object = dgSuiviClini.dataProvider;
    var todayDate:String= new DateUtility().DateAsToString(new Date());

    for(var i:Number=0; i < gData.length; i++)
    {
        var thisObj:Object = gData.getItemAt(i);
        if(thisObj.grDateDeb == todayDate)
        {
            dgSuiviClini.selectedIndex = i;
            //sometimes scrollToIndex doesnt work if validateNow() not done
            dgSuiviClini.validateNow();
                //dgSuiviClini.scrollToIndex(i);
        }
        else{
            dgSuiviClini.validateNow();
                // dgSuiviClini.scrollToIndex(gData.length);


        }
    }
    dgSuiviClini.validateNow();
    dgSuiviClini.editedItemPosition = { rowIndex: gData.length-1, columnIndex: nColSaisie };


}
```